# How To Save First REFERER Url With Jquery And Then Post It In A Hidden Form Text Field

Tags: jquery, cookies

Ive tried multiple solutions but when i actually tried it, they dont work.
Im looking for a way to save the referer URL, then the user keeps browsing the site until it lands on a contact page and submits. There i would like to post the url referer in a hidden text form field.

This needs to be done using just jquery.
Ive tried a jquery cookie plugin, but it didnt work for me.

Anyways, if somebody knows a working code to get this done and then post it in a text field it would really appreciate it.
In short: i need to store the http referer url in a session or cookie, then post it inside a form field that resides in a particular contact page.

Can somebody suggest a solution?

Comment: you said you tried something and did not work, post what you got so far; always try to post you progress

Comment: This should really be done on the server side, would save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: IS there any simple code that REALLY works to do this?
Ive tried this: http://www.webvanta.com/post/248172-capturing-source-codes-to-track-marketing it didnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

Sebastian ,

Store the referer value in the **cookie** and use it later.

Jquery cookie plugin should work for sure.

Comment: Could you please show me the code that works to do it in your opinion?

Comment: @sebastian , you mean setting the value in the cookie ??

Comment: No, i mean how to store that value first using the jquery cookie plugin, which script would u use to store it?

Comment: I found this didnt work when i tried it, can u please take a look and maybe suggest a code? Thanks
http://www.webvanta.com/post/248869-using-referrer-urls-to-better-understand